# Debug a start page in vs2008 with query string as startup parameter?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, query-string

Does anyone know how to set up a default querystring to an asp.net webform which is set up as a start up page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the start page for your project.

In the solution explorer right click on your web projects node and select properties.
Find the Web tab and select Specific Page and enter the name of the page you want to test and add your query string here.